# Linux OgreXML model viewer

Tags: 3d, models, ogre, linux, jmonkeyengine

Is there an OgreXML model viewer for Linux? I know about [OgreMax](http://www.ogremax.com/) but apparently that's Windows only.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [OgreMeshy](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Ogre+Meshy), but first the OgreXML file must be converted  to .mesh file with the command line tool OgreXmlConverter, included in the source code.

Comment: It requires Ogre 1.8.0 alpha, I version I can't find anywhere. I have 1.7.2 on my Ubuntu system from the PPA.

Comment: Have you tested the linux version of this post? http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=59600

Comment: All versions require 1.8.0

Comment: I haven't prove the binary because I don't have linux installed on my machine, but this version seems to be linked with Ogre in the binary. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Seconding OgreMeshy as I don't have enough rep to comment, though it does require 1.8.0 (so you'd have to build from [source](https://bitbucket.org/sinbad/ogre)).

Comment: Very strange considering how its creator looks badly upon tools that you need to compile from source.

Comment: If you can tell me where you would have liked the comment added I could add it to it.